# Securize "amount" variable when passing form to paypal with Buy Now button form

Tags: php, security, paypal, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on a standard paypal button "Buy Now". Currently I'm still working with Sandbox accounts but there's something weird...

Here is my HTML :

```
<input type="hidden" value="address@gmail.com" name="business">
<input type="hidden" value="EUR" name="currency_code">
<input type="hidden" value="FR" name="lc">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="encrypt">
<input type="hidden" value="http://mywebsite.com/paypal_ipn/process" name="notify_url">
<input type="hidden" value="http://mywebsite.com/thanks" name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="http://mywebsite.com/cancel" name="cancel_return">
<input type="hidden" value="Item 1" name="item_name">
<input type="hidden" value="0.89" name="amount">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="test">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="rm">
<input type="hidden" value="paynow" name="type">
<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">
```

I wanted to see if I could just change the `amount` value using web inspector (like Firebug) to change my product price before accessing Paypal transaction... and yes I just could buy my product with 0.01 instead of 0.89...

HOW CAN I SECURE THIS !!! THANKS

Comment: you check at the other end via IPN that the amount is correct; and the word is **secure** not *SECURIZE*

Comment: thank you for the reply (and for the english lesson as well), I'll try to do so

Comment: @Dagon something else: you mean that Paypal first check my `notify_url` before validate the purchase ? So Paypal do not take money from the 'hacker' if it's not the right price ?

Comment: validate the amount paypal says was paid, against the amount you think should be paid.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to generate encrypted PayPal buttons from within the PayPal site itself.  Folks cannot change the price or other items before sending them to the gateway.

Also, PayPal has an API that you can use to securely send information to their gateway.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside

> Direct Payment API offers you direct credit card payment processing capability through PayPal. For credit card transactions, customers stay on your website as PayPal processes the payment in the background.
>
> By integrating Direct Payment API with Express Checkout, as part of the Website Payments Pro solution, you can accept all major payment types, including PayPal, while working with a single provider that processes and manages all your online payments for you.

It's quite a bit more complex to get implemented than the "Generate Button" method, but it also has other benefits, namely better security and that the user does not have to leave your site to check out.